# question about pointers and overloading (.append() doesn't work in one line)

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010, pointers, overloading

In my program I would like to manipulate boost::filesystem::path elements of a vector in a for loop.

```
typedef vector<fs::path> path_vec;
path_vec pv;

for (auto it = pv.cbegin(), end = pv.cend(); it != end; ++it)
```

What I would like to do is to add a string to the end of the path.

If I do it like this, it works fine:

```
stringstream image_file_0001;
image_file_0001 << it->string() << "/x_alpha0001.png";
p1 = image_file_0001.str();
```

If I do it like this, it works fine too:

```
string a = it->string();
string b = a.append("/prx");
```

But if I try to do it in one line

```
string c = it->string().append("/prx");
```

or

```
string d = (it->string()).append("/prx");
```

it gives compile errors:

> 7 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer

I think it must be my lack of knowledge about how to use pointers, or is it something to do with the boost::filesystem::path .string() function?

OK, the thing I would like to do is to create a directory with `"/prx"` appended to the origianl path in `*it`. **Can I do it in one line?**

```
boost::filesystem::createdirectory ( something here );
```

What seems to be my problem is that I don't understand that why would .append() modify the original string. Isn't it a function which returns an other string, which I can use freely, while just reading the original string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fs::path.string()` returns const& so you cannot append anything to it, first you need to make a copy

but why do you do this at all? there's a obvious way to append nested path:

`path / nested_path`

EDIT:

```
typedef vector<fs::path> path_vec;
path_vec pv;

for (auto it = pv.begin(), end = pv.end(); it != end; ++it)
    *it /= "prx";
```

or to create directories instead of modifying vector values, replace the last line by:

```
fs::create_directory(*it / "prx");
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I do it in the obvious way? I never used nested_path. Also, why is .append() ruining the const, it is not modifying the string, it just returns an other string, isn't it?

Comment: no, `std::string::append()` does modify the string and returns itself. I added an example how to do what you need

Comment: OK, thanks, it works and its neat and tidy! BTW, it should be *it.

Comment: Could you correct it => *it? I would like to accept it, but not with the typo.

Answer (score 0):

`it->string()` is probably constant. Why don't you say:

```
const std::string a = it->string() + "/prx";
```

Comment: Can I say it in one line, like boost::filesystem::createdirectory ( something here ); ? Also, why is .append() ruining the const, it is not modifying the string, it just returns an other string, isn't it?

Comment: `append` modifies the string itself and returns `*this`, so no luck. What's wrong with writing `it->string() + "/prx"` in one line?